# How to get acknowledgement after sending sms successfully?

Tags: vb.net, sms

In my VB.Net Application, I have done with SMS sending using modem (dongle) as well as mobile phone connected to it.

I have done this using AT commands..
**I need to show acknowledgement / response on the screen after sending the sms.

How can i do this ?**

Some Code Snippet :

> ```
> If IsOpen = True Then
>         SMSPort.Write("AT" & vbCr)
>         SMSPort.Write("AT+CSCS=""GSM""" & vbCr)
>         SMSPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCr)
>         SMSPort.Write("AT+CMGS=""+91" & CellNumber & """" & vbCr)
>         _ContSMS = False
>         SMSPort.WriteLine(MyMessage & vbCrLf & Chr(26))
>         _Continue = False
>         RaiseEvent Sending(False)
>     End If
> ```

Answer (score 0):

-you need to make a recieve data event;

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports

Class PortDataReceived
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim mySerialPort As New SerialPort("COM1")

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None

    AddHandler mySerialPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

    mySerialPort.Open()

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadKey()
    mySerialPort.Close()
End Sub 

Private Shared Sub DataReceivedHandler(
                    sender As Object,
                    e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
    Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:")
    Console.Write(indata)
End Sub 
End Class
```

And then you need to figure out how to get a acknowledgement with your provider and hardware.

Comment: I tried -  MsgBox(SMSPort.ReadLine().ToString) but it shows blank.